# Problems with include function

Tags: php, include

I created a simple web site with php pages. I had all pages in the same directory: /var/www/ ;
the index.php page is similar to this:

```
    <?php 
     include ("Header.php");
     include ("Menu.php");
     include ("Content.php");
     include ("Footer.php");
    ?>
```

When all these php files are in the same directory , the web site works good. If I insert, for example, the page Menu.php in the directory /var/www/NewFolder , the web site doesn't work. I changed the index.php file:

```
   <?php
    include ("Header.php");
    **include ("NewFolder/Menu.php")**;
    include ("Content.php");
    include ("Footer.php");
   ?>
```

Did I make a mistake to write the directory ?

Comment: what is your root path ?

Comment: Doesn't work ? What is the error log ?

Comment: Check includes in "NewFolder/Menu.php" file. They are relative to the running script location

Comment: what does "the web site doesn't work" mean? What error is it returning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
include (dirname(__FILE__) . "/NewFolder/Menu.php");
```

Comment: *cough* `__DIR__` *cough*

Comment: Yes, can be used that also